# symfony 3 formbuilder order properties

Tags: php, symfony

Using symfony 3, how can I customize form property order?

In my BookType class, I add my properties in my custom order, but when rendered, form will display in another order. Why?

```
class BookType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('author')
        ->add('pages')
        ->add('published_date')
        ->add('views');

    }

}
```

And this is the result:

- author
- title
- pages
- views
- published_date

Thx in advance

Comment: Generally no-one ever uses the form component as is. You should render each row separately in your view.

Comment: I can not believe that it is not expected an order utility in FormConfigurator

Comment: Is it because your entity is in a different order? Even if it is, the idea of an MVC is to separate view logic from business logic. The view is where you define how a page should look, this includes the ordering of forms.

Comment: In my Entity properties are in different order, but I don't believe that there is no option in FormBuilder for setting properties order

Comment: I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Why? What do you mean?

Comment: I repeat. The view is the place to define view related logic e.g ordering.

Comment: I don't think so... I think that order can be configurated☝️

Comment: fabpot 
commented 4 months ago

Closing this old PR as it does not seem that there is a consensus. Having order only at the template level seems like the best way to go.

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11241 , if the man in charge says no then it really is a no...

Comment: How do you render your form?

Comment: I'm using pektopara admin generator

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your form result by using form_row(form.author) for each field you have to display. have a look there:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-basics

Comment: Sure, if I modify my twig files, but I would set property order from FormBuilder 

Comment: In must case  form_widget(form) should render all your fields as described inside your form_builder

Comment: Symfony now has Form Field Sorting https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-form-field-sorting